# I search an example of an ad hominem argument, which is not simultaneously an argument from analogy

Tags: logic, argumentation, analogy

Incidentally I found an old copy from a book, with this claim: “Hence most ad hominem criticisms are really forms of the argument from analogy” (Douglas Walton, Ad Hominem Arguments, Tuscaloosa, The University of Alabama Pr., 1998, p. 196).

Walton is one of the greatest authorities on argumentation theory. From this text passage, the question arises whether we may find an example of an ad hominem argument, which is not also simultaneously an argument from analogy.

(This is a new, less broad version of the question posed on 10 June 2017; note that the comments until 12 June 2017 refer to the previous version.)

Comment: The *argumentum ad hominem* is a [Fallacy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fallacies/).

Comment: The [argument from analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_analogy) is a type of inductive argument.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA: The argumentum ad hominem must not necessarily be a fallacy. … Because it may be a valid analogy. Problems with a person in previous situations (this is the inductive argument you mentioned in the above comment) may be deductively conveyed (by analogy) into a new situation. Why should this be fallacious?

Comment: @Zeus there is an internet forum rule "take the ball not the man"

Comment: @user3293056: But, at a certain point, it is – also in the internet − a rule to use the argumentum ad hominem; to wit when they call somebody a troll; and this is hardly regarded as a fallacy. Additionally, this is also an argument from analogy, since the former negative experience with the man is conveyed into the future as negative prognosis. `Thus, the suspicion arises that the argumentum ad hominem is a subclass of the argument from analogy.` −  And if this were true, this whole field of argumentation theory would be wanting (since I see dozens of ignored similar coherences).

Comment: The "coherence" is simply that one can use analogies to produce creative ad hominems. One can also use analogies to produce a host of other things, including physical models, as Maxwell did by describing electromagnetism using mechanical ether. But X being used for Y is a far cry from X being a subclass of Y. Bad arguments often have multiple fallacies packed into them, and sometimes it is even hard to distinguish which ones exactly. There is no principled classification of fallacies, they are just vague pointers. Perhaps your confusion comes from looking for depth that isn't there.

Comment: @Conifold, but you misunderstood me. Your above argumentation is that `X being used for Y` cannot lead to `X being a subclass of Y.` − But this is not what I proposed. I proposed that it leads to the reverse, namely  _`Y being a subclass of X`_ , and this works! − Please revise what you have said with the correct order of X and Y in the italicized sentence above. −− What Maxwell did (i.e. Y, his electromagnetic models) are by definition analogies, ...

Comment: … hence they are, of course, a subclass of X (=`ANALOGIES in general, as class` − of course not of those specific analogies, which he used, as you erroneously claimed). The essence of scientific models is that they are analogies, hence models are a subclass of ANALOGY. For instance, a map is naturally an analogy of the real landscape. It is a model, and each model is an analogy.

Comment: @All readers: I made a radical change of the title and text of the question. Essentially the question remains the same, but now it is less broad and more answerable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that most *ad hominem* arguments are analogies. Comparisons of people to Hitler and Stalin are among the most familiar. Often the comparison is inappropriate, but it is still an analogy.

However, I would say that the truly irrelevant *ad hominem* argument fails even as an analogy. Person A argues that two plus two equals four, and Person B disagrees, pointing out that Person A has been convicted of a crime. There is no comparison of Person A to anyone, only the allegation that a character defect can invalidate the answer to an arithmetic problem.

Comment: But the substantiated character defect refers to an act in the past, which is conveyed into the presence. How is it conveyed? By analogy-assisted deduction, i.e. someone who does not know that 2+2=4 does not believe him because he lied in the past.

Comment: Or, as noted above it is a genetic fallacy and not an analogy, misattributing different aspects of an identity causation of different sorts that are not traceable causally.  Lying doesn't make you bad at arithmetic, and lying about arithmetic is silly, since third parties can check it.

Answer (score 1):

Ad hominem arguments are also often genetic fallacies.  "Why should we consider the logic of a lesbian about family planning?"  "Don't even bother to start mansplaining."  "How could you know what is wrong with our two-party system?  You aren't even an American!"

This can't really be an argument from analogy, because bigotry is resistant to previous experience and is often formed in the absence of evidence.

The assumption that two lesbians/men/foreigners will be alike in some way is, in some sense, an analogy, but it is not reasonable to assume that this is one of those ways.  So the genetic fallacy kicks in before the analogy has any basis for application.

Answer (score 0):

What about an argument that says: "He completed the first grade, and now he comes to us and tells us how to run our atomic supercollider. Absurd." In the case that we are speaking to an excellent Princeton physicist, i.e., the argument simply leaves out the rest of the educational attainment, but does not lie.

Any such distortion through selection of the facts seems to 'slander the speaker, rather than speak to his merits or those of his argument,' if that is what is meant by "ad hominem argument" in this question.

Maybe more accurate is simply to say: He has always been wrong about everything. Simply a fact about him.

Although, it is as though we make an analogy by suggesting that the way he has been up till now, is like, alike, the way he is now.

Perhaps, strict sense, the form of ad hominem is itself analogy, between past and present.

--

I would add in passing that "ad hominem" has, also, quite distinctly different senses.